# Match and Extract all arithmetic expression in a string in python

Tags: python

suppose I have string

```
exp = '("function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY" * "function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")'
```

or a expression string with function Round

```
exp = 'Round(("function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY" * "function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE"),2 )'
```

The arithmetic operator can be any[+-/%*] and can appear any number of times in expression. I want to check if a expression contains arithmetic operator calculation if yes return the expression in list and return true.

for exp1 **exp = '("function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY" * "function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE" '** the expected result is True and returned output ['("function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY" * "function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")']

for exp2 **exp = 'Round(("function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY" - "function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE"),2 )'** the expected result is True and returned output ['("function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY" -"function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")']

This is what I have used a regex to check if the string expression contains arithmetic operation

```
expression = '("function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."QUANTITY" * "function_test"."ORDER_ITEMS"."UNIT_PRICE")'
if bool(re.search(r'(.*?)[\/\+\-\*](.*?)',expression )) == True:
   print('True')
```

but it does not parse the expression properly. Please help

Comment: You have a stray `]` inside your regexp - did you mean to keep that there? (inside of `(.*?\])`) - It's not present in any of your examples that you're trying to match. You also have an unbalanced parenthesis at the start of your regex - and if you want your parenthesis to be part of the match statement you'd need to escape them.

Comment: Why can you not just use: `r'\*|\-|\+|%|/'` as the regex? I tried it with the above string and it returned True for me

Comment: @MatsLindh sorry editted  my regex it was a typo

Comment: @user15270287 But i also want the expression involved in the arithmetic operation in a list as a output as i mentioned in my description

Comment: Do you count `'false-positive'` as an arithmetical expression? What about `'***********'`?

Comment: @JohnColeman No what do you mean by `false-positive`

Comment: @shee You seem to be defining arithmetical expressions as simply being strings which contain arithmetical operators. That is a fairly loose definition, which also admits strings such as `'*************'` that are not arithmetical in any usual meaning of the word. It also admits things like `'2+3-(/2*'` which are at best ill-formed expressions. If what you are *really* interested in are actual arithmetical expressions but your test is a regex which just tests for the presence of operators, your code will (depending on the input of course) have false positives.

Comment: @JohnColeman As I have said my code might work to check the presence of arithmetic operator in a expression but I need to extract all arithmetic calculation from string to an output list for my further process.A string can have any number of calculations and I need all the calculation expresssion in a output list